# How to find out all the images which are created by performing commit on the particular container?

Tags: docker

With GET /images/json rest API, I get the following information about a image

```
[
    {
        .....
        **"Id": "35ae2647a35e3f93ed33d109daec2c1cca11662d0372e959d4d7a39f44a031f3",**
        "Labels": {},
        "ParentId": "91e54dfb11794fad694460162bf0cb0a4fa710cfa3f60979c177d920813e267c",
        .....
]
```

And with GET /images/35ae/json, I get following information about a image

```
{
    ....

    "Container": "a9b29366c7c253628a969653464cb651a8f554ac23c4f439582db94cd5304b39",
    **"Id": "35ae2647a35e3f93ed33d109daec2c1cca11662d0372e959d4d7a39f44a031f3",**
    "Os": "linux",
    "Parent": "91e54dfb11794fad694460162bf0cb0a4fa710cfa3f60979c177d920813e267c",
    .....   
}
```

We can see that the endpoint "GET /images//json" has container ID which is responsible for the creation of this image. This information is missing for the image in the "GET /images/json" endpoint.

**My goal is to find out all the images which are created by performing commit on the particular container.**

Since container ID is missing in the output of "GET /images/json" endpoint , I am currently getting the list of all the images using API "GET /images/json" and for each image, use "GET /images//json" to get the parent container ID.

**I would like to know if there is way to achieve the goal without making "GET /images//json" API call for each image.**

Thanks.

Comment: I didn't get your question. What do you want to do? The two APIs are for different purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The `container` property of an image is "the id of the container used to commit"; this may refer to a container that was running at Docker, or on the machine of the maintainer of some project; not very useful unless you are doing forensics.

To find all the containers on your system, do `GET /containers/json`, then you can go from each of those to its image.